# python openAI retro module

Tags: python, anaconda, openai-gym

I am trying to use the retro module and I jupyter notebooks I seemed to install it with a `!pip install retro` where it went thru the download/install ok.

But when I try to `import retro` I get an error

`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/benbartling/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2963, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-1-81066d3a41c5>", line 1, in <module>
    import retro

  File "/home/benbartling/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/retro/__init__.py", line 206
    print "%s: %s" % (key, value)
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Would anyone have any ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you installed the wrong retro? That retro you installed seems to be [this](https://pypi.org/project/Retro/), which seems to be a toolkit for developing web apps and is most likely not ported to python3.+ hence failing at `SyntaxError` for the `print` statement. The openAI retro you were looking for is [here](https://github.com/openai/retro) and the installation command is `pip3 install gym-retro`.

Comment: any idea if the wrong retro module can be uninstalled? Can pip uninstall a python package?

Comment: try `pip uninstall retro` (see [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_uninstall/))